# Miller's manager was not amused

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image: Empty crossword grid]

[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2p83xm95)

**Across**
1. Communist revolutionary's injector – in short, it might move water from the tap into a sprayer (8)
6. Bone in the arm of cool American shown around India (6)
7. European prophet given ban when touching Australian's clothing (8)
8. Base for informant located inside Eurasian range (6)
9. Parrots sorted peas (4)
12. Abridged Murphy novel refused backing of Sir Hill (4)
15. Scientist's creature that terrorises people – five missing, one turned into stone, ultimately (6)
17. Put together Degas's emblematic piece (8)
18. Cheater fabricated a large area (7)
19. Bed of singer in exuberant surroundings (8)

**Down**
1. Frothy foam maybe covering Miller's manager (4)
2. Buffalo man with rabies struggling, losing self (5)
3. Take piano in (5)
4. Spam disseminated about ending of metal song (5)
5. Soviet Navy encircles mountain on Mediterranean island (4)
10. Ottoman dignitary's dad has got grey (5)
11. Documentation for auditor's tiny spots (5)
13. Keith who writes songs living in the city (5)
14. Laboratory broken into by male beast that's young (4)
16. Force seer to undress surface of their limbs (4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

Answers and explanations:

**Across**

> 1. **HOSEPIPE** *HO'S EPIPE(-n)* Communist revolutionary's injector – in short, it might move water from the tap into a sprayer (8)
> 6. **RADIUS** *RAD US around I* Bone in the arm of cool American shown around India (6)
> 7. **ALBANIAN** *AL(BAN)I touching A(-ustralia)N* European prophet given ban when touching Australian's clothing (8)
> 8. **URACIL** *URA(CI)L* Base for informant located inside Eurasian range (6)
> 9. **APES** *PEAS** Parrots sorted peas (4)
> 12. **HUMP** *(MURPH(-y))* minus (-si)R* Abridged Murphy novel refused backing of Sir Hill (4)
> 15. **AMPERE** *VAMPIRE minus V, I -> E* Scientist's creature that terrorises people – five missing, one turned into stone, ultimately (6)
> 17. **ASSEMBLE** *substring* Put together Degas's emblematic piece (8)
> 18. **HECTARE** *CHEATER** Cheater fabricated a large area (7)
> 19. **BASSINET** *BASS IN E(-xuberan)T* Bed of singer in exuberant surroundings (8)

**Down**

> 1. **HEAD** *ddef; I think Miller's is a brand of beer* Frothy foam maybe covering Miller's manager (4)
> 2. **SABRE** *RAB(-i)ES** Buffalo man with rabies struggling, losing self (5)
> 3. **PINCH** *P + INCH* Take piano in (5)
> 4. **PSALM** *SPAM* about (-meta)L* Spam disseminated about ending of metal song (5)
> 5. **ETNA** *substring* Soviet Navy encircles mountain on Mediterranean island (4)
> 10. **PASHA** *PA containing ASH* Ottoman dignitary's dad has got grey (5)
> 11. **SPECS** *sounds like SPECKS* Documentation for auditor's tiny spots (5)
> 13. **URBAN** *ddef* Keith who writes songs living in the city (5)
> 14. **LAMB** *LA(M)B* Laboratory broken into by male beast that's young (4)
> 16. **FEET** *F (-s)EE(-r) T(-heir)* Force seer to undress surface of their limbs (4)

Confession:

> I don't see why CI means "informant" in 8a.

Quibbles:

> I'm not sure Ali was a *prophet*. I'm not wild about the *almost*-symmetrical grid :-).

Comment: Nicely done! Fair enough about Ali, not sure what I was thinking there. The informant term is from US cop shows (the C is from either "confidential" or "criminal", I think both terms are used).

Comment: Ah! I have never watched any of those :-).

Comment: Oops, just noticed that one answer isn't listed or explained in the section where I'm meant to be doing that. Fixing now.

Comment: (Also, I somehow had Qxw configured not to include numbers in completed-grid images. Fixed that too.)

Comment: Very impressive. What is the significance of "Buffalo man" in 2 down?

Comment: @butterflyknife https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_Sabres